# When browser's back button pushed, confirm form resubmission problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the confirm form resubmission appears, I confirmed that the request is going to the server when I click refresh.

I want the request to go automatically to the server when the user presses back, without a screen to confirm the form resubmission.

```
      if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
        window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
      };
```

When entering this code, it is not the desired behavior because it is refreshed without payload. Is there any way to refresh by getting a payload?

The reason for thinking like this is that the payload is automatically delivered on refresh, so I think there is a way to get it.

Comment: can you share your work little bit more so I can explain you?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.